# How to calculate values of a drop down menu with PHP/ JS?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hi I have been very puzzled how to do this and cannot find any relevant tutorial that could help me so I thought I would ask here and hope to find the help.

I have a form with 2 drop down menus, each of them having a `value` attribute. What I want to do is allow someone to pick one item off one drop down and another off the other drop down.

Once both drop downs have an item picked, the person is shown a total sum which is accumulated off the values from Drop Down 1 and Drop Down 2

Here is my code which is nowhere near anything correct.

```
<form>
echo "<select name=Postage>
  <option value='14'>1st Class</option>
  <option value='8'>2nd Class</option>
  <option value='22'>Next Day Delivery</option>
  <option value='0'>Click And Collect</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name=Type>";

$type = "SELECT * FROM $category order by id";
$item = mysql_query($type);
while ($typeitem = mysql_fetch_assoc($item)) {

echo "<option value=$typeitem[price]>$typeitem[type]</option>";

}

$totalspend = Type.value + Postage.value;

echo "
Total £$totalspend
</select>
</form>";
```

I understand I will get replies saying you need to do this through javascript, but I have no idea how to implement this into a javascript code.

Any help please?

Comment: You will need to use Ajax for what you are trying to do, this example will help you I hope http://www.html-form-guide.com/jquery/drop-down-list-jquery.html

Comment: Yup, like Balder said, the only way is to use Ajax.  Here's a resource that might help - http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/ajax_drop_down_list3.php

Comment: This is not a situation that requires AJAX. Simple javascript can be used to calculate and display a value based on the values from the menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure by your question if you want to add it to the db on the selection... that would require a simple but different code. This will accomplish what you are asking.

You do not need a form... just the selection boxes. If you notice I encased each piece of html in an echo tag... this writes a minimized code to the browser.

You have to `id` each selection box as follows:

HTML

```
echo '<select id="this_postage" name="Postage">';
        echo '<option value="14">1st Class</option>';
        echo '<option value="8">2nd Class</option>';
        echo '<option value="22">Next Day Delivery</option>';
        echo '<option value="0">Click And Collect</option>';
    echo '</select>';   

    echo '<select id="this_type" name="Type">';
        $type = "SELECT * FROM $category order by id";
        $item = mysql_query($type);
        while ($typeitem = mysql_fetch_assoc($item)) {  
            echo '<option value='.$typeitem[price].'>'.$typeitem[type].'</option>'; 
        }
    echo '</select>';

    echo '<div id="total_spend"></div>';
```

Notice the div with `id="total_spend"`.

JQUERY

```
$(function() {  
    $( "#this_type" ).change(function(){
        var total_spend = parseInt($('#this_postage').val()) + parseInt($('#this_type').val());
        $('#total_spend').html('Total: £'+total_spend);
});
```

When the user selects the `Type` the jQuery will pick up the change and get the values of both the postage and type and add them and then render the total in the `<div id="total_spend">Total: £TOTAL HERE</div>`

THIS CODE WILL SEND TO DB:

Again no form tag required:

HTML:

Added hidden input to hold processing URL

```
echo '<input type="hidden" id="updateURL" value="PATH-TO-PHP-PROCESSING-FILE.PHP">';
    echo '<select id="this_postage" name="Postage">';
        echo '<option value="14">1st Class</option>';
        echo '<option value="8">2nd Class</option>';
        echo '<option value="22">Next Day Delivery</option>';
        echo '<option value="0">Click And Collect</option>';
    echo '</select>';   

    echo '<select id="this_type" name="Type">';
        $type = "SELECT * FROM $category order by id";
        $item = mysql_query($type);
        while ($typeitem = mysql_fetch_assoc($item)) {  
            echo '<option value='.$typeitem[price].'>'.$typeitem[type].'</option>'; 
        }
    echo '</select>';

    echo '<div id="total_spend"></div>';
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function() {
$( "#this_type" ).change(function(){
        var url = $('#updateURL').val();        
        var postage = parseInt($('#this_postage').val());   
        var type = parseInt($('#this_type').val());
        var total_spend = (postage + type);
        var postit = $.post( url, {
        custom_block_name:custom_block_name,
        postage:postage,
        type:type
        });     
        postit.done(function( data ) {
        alert(data);
        $('#total_spend').html('Total: £'+total_spend);
        });     
    });});
```

Treat the processing php as you would with the post method. At the bottom under the mysql update code you can 
`echo 'Whatever Message you want to render in the alert message here.';`

If you do not want an alert remove it from the jquery

TO CALL jQUERY

```
...?>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function() { 
        $( "#this_type" ).change(function(){
            var total_spend = parseInt($('#this_postage').val()) + parseInt($('#this_type').val());
            $('#total_spend').html('Total: £'+total_spend);
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: yes I do not want to add anything to the database I was only retrieving data from the database and adding the 2 values together. With that java though do I keep it on the same php file or do I have to distinguish it in a new file?

Comment: It is up to you... if you keep it on the php file you need to add `<script>PUT JQUERY HERE</script>` You will also need to link to jquery if you haven't already on the page. I would link to your jquery at the bottom of the page and put the above script tag beneath the jquey link with both below your closing `?>`

Comment: @Diamonddallas I edited the code... spaced on putting in `parseInt()` see the second answer from @Maverick976

Comment: I got the menu all up and running but it has to be where I am entering this script for the java where I must be really messing up. so after my whole php document is shut off <?PHP ?> after that I have put <script type="text/javascript"> JQUERY </script> I guess what I'm missing here is a reference to that <script> tag as selecting the items off the drop down list does not update anything or show a total_spend

Comment: @DiamondDallas ... sry about not getting back went to eat... I added the code you need to call the juery in the answer

Comment: no problem, do they do private messages here? I got a query it revolves around how to change that post section, how do I do it that there is a if statement that says if $item[measurement] <= "3" then the value is 8.50 else if its between 4 or 9 then value is 12.50 else if its >= "10" then value is 18.50

Comment: It appears you are more familiar with php... I would use the second example and calculate in php and return the answer in data

Comment: To return the data in the second example delete `alert(data);` and replace `$('#total_spend').html('Total: £'+total_spend);` with `$('#total_spend').html('Total: £'+data);`

Answer (score 1):

You could display the total with a few lines of jquery.  Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/f445vfjk/

```
<select class="postage demo" name='Postage'>
    <option value='0'>Please select postage...</option>
    <option value='14'>1st Class</option>
    <option value='8'>2nd Class</option>
    <option value='22'>Next Day Delivery</option>
    <option value='0'>Click And Collect</option>
</select>

<!-- example output from PHP -->
<select class="type demo" name='Type'>
    <option value='0'>Please select type...</option>
    <option value='12'>Box</option>
    <option value='5'>Envelope</option>
    <option value='3'>Card</option>
</select>

<label>Total:</label>
<input name='total' id='total' disabled='true' value=''>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.demo').change(function(){
        var postage = parseInt($('.postage').val());
        var type = parseInt($('.type').val());
        var total = postage + type;
        $('#total').val('$' + total.toFixed(2));
    }); 
});
```